# Namespacing jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Let's assume that we have following jQuery plugins (each of them in separate files):

- `$.fn.foo`
- `$.fn.foo.bar`
- `$.fn.foo.baz`

I use standard jQuery plugin pattern. The first one is actually a proxy or "facade" to the rest plugins of it's namespace.
For example, when I call `$('#el').foo()`, under the hood I also call:

```
var context = this; // context is equal to $('#el')
$(context).foo['bar'].apply(context);
$(context).foo['baz'].apply(context);
```

There are two problem when I want to call *only* (without `$.fn.foo`) `$('#el').foo.bar()`. The first problem is that there are no `$.fn.foo` namespace but I can create it, so this is actually no problem. The second problem is that `this` inside `$.fn.foo.bar` is equal to `document` object but I want to be equal to `$('#el')`. How can I do that?

So, making a long story short, both should work:

```
$('#el').foo();     // This also calls foo.bar and foo.baz under the hood
$('#el').foo.bar(); // I'm calling foo.bar explicitly
```

Comment: Isn't calling "$(context).foo['baz'].apply(context);" redundant shouldn't it just be "$(context).foo['baz'];"

Comment: @Keith If he calls it that way, `this` will be the document rather than the element it was called on.

Comment: This kind of namespacing is rage. Please write a sensible architecture like modular code, or using any functional or OO pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might just need to follow a different plugin pattern. Here is a nice [repository of jQuery plugin patterns](https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-plugin-patterns), but the one you might want to look at would be the [namespace pattern](https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-plugin-patterns/blob/master/jquery.namespace.plugin-boilerplate.js) - you'll see how the namespace gets defined initially if it doesn't already exist, and this allows you to more easily extend from a single namespace across multiple scripts.

---

Update: Hmm, I'm still learning so I wouldn't say I'm an expert at this, but trying to get this `$('#el').aaa.bbb.ccc()` to work got really messy for me. Maybe it would be better to not use that format, but instead do this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/6NZDe/)):

```
$.aaa.bbb.ccc( $("#el") );
```

because then it is relatively easy to set up:

```
(function() {
    if (!$.aaa) {
        $.aaa = {
            bbb : {
                ccc: function(el, options){
                    alert(el[0].id);
                }
            }
        };
    };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    $.aaa.bbb.ccc( $("#el") ); // alerts "el"
});
```

Comment: Hm...Maybe this is not what I'm exactly looking for but it's definetely useful link. I'm asking only one question: In statement like `$('#el').aaa.bbb.ccc()` is possible to get `this` equals to `$('#el')` in function `ccc`?